# Generating dynamic Wordpress web pages from external DB

Tags: node.js, wordpress

Here is what I'm really trying to do.

My website is a social network with user profile pages, and I want them to be accessed by ex. http://www.socialnetwork.com/profile123

How would I do this with Wordpress?

Here is my thinking on how it would work:
-User enters the URL from the browser
-Link hits the server, server reads the string profile123.
-Server fetches profile info from DB and generates a new HTML page.
-Server responds with the new HTML page.

The question is thew web server is Wordpress and my DB is served somewhere else via REST API, is there a way to use some plugins to have wordpress securely communicate with my server to generate a page like i envisioned?

If not, how do you(pros) usually do it?

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress have very well documented functions for using external API.
Just read the documentation here-
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/http-api/

Comment: I did say securely.  I need https. Also this API is what Wordpress serves correct? Not what we can use to access other API services like Twitter or Yelp.

Comment: Also how to generate a new webpage using the data retrieved after he get request

Comment: Well now I got it. Its clean and simple.

Comment: Well now I got it. Its clean and simple.
Usually Website is working like this, PHP fetch data from DB and output them as HTML.

just change the last step, just make php script to echo them to a json or xml format. So the end user will fetch them as json object and use them to create a html view.

Comment: Any plugins I can use to do this?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/ 
this is good one to use in wordpress.